# Problemas ao instanciar objeto num vetor pelo return de um método - JAVA

Tags: java, array

Eu tenho o seguinte método da classe Loja que tem como função preencher as variáveis de um objeto do tipo Venda (além de modificar um produto de acordo com a quantidade de produtos vendidos passado no parâmetro).

```
public Venda realizarVenda(int codigoCliente, int codigoProduto, int quantidade){

       Venda v = new Venda();
       for(int i = 0 ; this.clientes[i].getCodigo() != 0 ; i++){
           if(this.clientes[i].getCodigo() == codigoCliente){
               v.setCliente(this.clientes[i].getNome());
               v.setCodigoVenda(codigoCliente+codigoProduto);
               v.setProduto(this.produtos[codigoProduto-1].getNome());
               v.setQuantidade(quantidade);
               this.produtos[codigoProduto-1].setQuantidade
               (this.produtos[codigoProduto-1].getQuantidade()- quantidade);
           }
       }
       return v;
   }
```

Acontece que, ao tentar chamar a função com a linha:

```
loja.getVendas()[0].setVendas(loja.realizarVenda(1112, 7, 8));
```

Dá o erro:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol:method setVendas(Venda)
location: class Venda
```

variáveis da classe loja e construtor:

```
public class Loja {
    private Produto[] produtos;
    private Cliente[] clientes;
    private Venda[] vendas;

    public Loja (int quantidadeProdutos, int quantidadeClientes, int quantidadeVendas) {
    this.produtos = new Produto[quantidadeProdutos];
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeProdutos; i++) {
        this.produtos[i] = new Produto(); 
        }
    this.clientes = new Cliente[quantidadeClientes];
        for (int j = 0; j < quantidadeClientes; j++) {
        this.clientes[j] = new Cliente(); 
        }
    this.vendas = new Venda[quantidadeVendas];
        for (int k = 0; k < quantidadeVendas; k++) {
        this.vendas[k] = new Venda(); 
        }
    }
```

Como instanciar corretamente o objeto que está sendo passado como parâmetro no método em um vetor de objetos?
Os getters e setters de um vetor de objetos devem ser configurados diferentemente da forma padrão?

exemplo de como estão os getters e setters:

```
public Venda[] getVendas() {
    return vendas;
}

public void setVendas(Venda[] vendas) {
    this.vendas = vendas;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na linha `loja.getVendas()[0].setVendas(loja.realizarVenda(1112, 7, 8));` você está tentando fazer o `setVendas(...)` de uma variável do tipo `Venda` e não do array `vendas` da classe `Loja` do seu código.

O erro acontece pois a classe `Venda` não possui o método `setVendas`, quem possui acredito que seja a classe `Loja`.

Observe que o seu método `setVendas(Venda[] vendas)` espera um array de vendas e não um objeto do tipo `Venda` que é o que você está passando para ele como o retorno da função `public Venda realizarVenda(..)`

Se eu entendi corretamente o que quer, você apenas precisa fazer:

`loja.getVendas()[0] = loja.realizarVenda(1112, 7, 8);`